# Change Background For Every Link in Custom Menu Extension Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7 CE. I am trying to edit the look of the Custom Menu extension. For the top menu I am trying to have every main category to have a different background color. Does anoyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the user guide on background images on http://store.belvg.com/background-pages.html#product_overview . Thanks ,Zakir

Comment: Please, extend your answer with more details, some extract from a link, you've provided. This link could be later lost... but SO will keep your answer.